# Pyspark-object has no attribute 'spark'

Tags: python, pyspark, pytest

```
    from unittest import TestCase

from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from lib.utils import load_survey_df, count_by_country


class UtilsTestCase(TestCase):
    @classmethod
    def create_testing_pyspark_session(cls):
        return SparkSession.builder.master('local[2]').appName('my - local - testing - pyspark - context').getOrCreate()

    @classmethod
    def SetUpClass(cls) -> None:
        cls.spark = cls.create_testing_pyspark_session()

    def test_datafile_loading(self):
        sample_df = load_survey_df(self.spark, "data/sample.csv")
        result_count = sample_df.count()
        self.assertEqual(result_count, 9, "Record count should be 9")

    def test_country_count(self):
        sample_df = load_survey_df(self.spark, "data/sample.csv")
        count_list = count_by_country(sample_df).collect()
        count_dict = dict()
        for row in count_list:
            count_dict[row["Country"]] = row["count"]
        self.assertEqual(count_dict["United States"], 4, "Count for United States should be 4")
        self.assertEqual(count_dict["Canada"], 2, "Count for United States should be 2")
        self.assertEqual(count_dict["United Kingdom"], 1, "Count for United States should be 1")
```

Hi All,
Can you please tell me what's wrong with this code? I am getting below error:
Error
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\abc\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\unittest\case.py", line 59, in testPartExecutor
yield
File "C:\Users\abc\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\unittest\case.py", line 628, in run
testMethod()
File "C:\Users\abc\PycharmProjects\HelloSpark\lib\test_utils.py", line 17, in test_datafile_loading
sample_df = load_survey_df(self.spark, "data/sample.csv")
AttributeError: 'UtilsTestCase' object has no attribute 'spark'

Comment: It's `setUpClass`, not `SetUpClass`.

Answer (score 0):

I see that within your `SetUpClass` method you are using `cls.spark`,
you need to *declare* is as `attribute` in `class UtilsTestCase`.

just adding `spark` after your class to your code as follows should fix it:

```
class UtilsTestCase(TestCase):
  spark
  @classmethod
  def create_testing_pyspark_session(cls):
    return SparkSession.builder.master('local[2]').appName('my - local - testing - pyspark - context').getOrCreate()

  @classmethod
  def SetUpClass(cls) -> None:
    cls.spark = cls.create_testing_pyspark_session()
```